# Adding a checkbox in header of checkbox column in data grid view using windows form vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, checkbox, windows-forms-designer

I have a functioning data grid view which displays all data of my databases with corresponding checkboxes..

```
Private Sub Recipients_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = <SQL> SELECT Idno,Name,YearSec,Course,Organization FROM tbl_students </SQL>.Value

    Dim myadap As New MySqlDataAdapter(mycom)
    Dim mydt As New DataTable

    mydt.Columns.Add("", GetType(Boolean))
    myadap.Fill(mydt)
    grdRecipients.DataSource = mydt
    myadap.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

I have a problem of creating a checkbox in the header of my checkbox column, can anyone help me, i didnt started any code yet.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20165/CheckBox-Header-Column-For-DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim chkbx As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(chkbx)
chkbx.HeaderText = "Check Box"
chkbx.Name = "checkBox"
```

or manually

```
AddColumn... -> Type = DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
```

valter

Comment: @DivineGraceBlanza The first one is when you are creating columns dynamically with code. The second one in the designer.